# Xml / Filesystem concurrent access

Tags: xml, vb.net, filesystems

I am rewriting our in-house content management system and migrating from a database to an xml-based system. I know there are a lot out there that do this already. I do have a few concerns and I was hoping to get your opinion on them.

WRITING

Can a user be writing to an xml document and another user be reading it concurrently. I am NOT using XMLDocument or XMLTextWriter for the write operation.

READING

Can multiple users parse an xml file concurrently and will there be a significant drop in speed? I am using XMLDocument for reading.

I guess I am talking milliseconds here for most operations. I just am worried about it.

Comment: XML is not so good for large data volumes so you should have reasons to do this migration (common sense offers migration in opposite direction)).

Answer (score 0):

- Writing

  It depends on how you update the XML file. If you do your updates atomically, there should be no problem. In that case, the update that finishes last wins.

  To update files atomically, first open and write a temporary file with a unique name. When you are finished writing it, close it and then rename it on top of the original file. All other processes that are still using the old copy will continue to do so but new processes that open the file will get the new version.
- Reading

  There really isn't an issue here. Readers will not interfere with one another. The only drop in performance you will get is the normal drop in performance associated with sharing a CPU between multiple processes.

Comment: Thank you. I am doing it this way but wanted to make sure my assumptions where correct.